# How to fetch weekday name from date saved in timeStamp in Flutter / Firebase

Tags: flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, dayofweek

I am saving my `timeStamp` to Firestore as `DateTime.now()`.
Now, I need to retrieve from this timeStamp a specific day of the week.

For example to reset some variables every `Monday` morning.

Please help how it should be done.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore’s timestamp contains a method called [**`toDate()`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) method that will return a dart `DateTime` object.

`toDate()`:

```
timestamp.toDate(); // e.g 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

From the return of the method, you can now use regular Dart solutions. You can use [**`DateFormat`**](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) library to display it as day of the week.

`DateFormat`:

```
DateFormat('EEEE').format(date); // e.g Monday
```